# Mysql query to search for credit card numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I am not a developer or a MySQL DBA (far from it!) but regularly deal with MySQL databases at the moment. I've searched high and low but can't get my head around writing a regular expression query for this so reaching out to the experts.

I would like to know if anyone can give me a hint on how to write a MySQL query which would return results for a credit card number in a field...

- A card number in the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
- A card number with just the 16 digits with no dashes

The goal is to search our MySQL databases for cardholder data so we can basically get rid...!

Many thanks in advance
Sarah

Comment: Not a REGEX, but anyway... `REPLACE(string,'-',''')`

Comment: What results do you want?  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Don't forget about American Express. Their card numbers are 15 digits, and the format is `xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx`

Comment: `REPLACE(string,'-',''') REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{15,16}$'` -- this assumes the entire string is just the CC#.  If you are looking for it in the middle of longer strings, then remove the anchors (`^` and `$`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate the field using a regular expression:

```
where cardnumber regexp '^[0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{4}$'
```

Comment: Great that looks exactly what I need! 

is there a way to search for a 16 digit numeric string (Without dashes)?

Comment: @SarahCurtis . . . This makes the queries optional.  But you could just use `'^[0-9]{16}$'`.